# Which of these Array Initializations is better in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, arrays, memory, initialization

Which of these two forms of Array Initialization is better in Ruby?

**Method 1:**

```
DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = (0..6).to_a
HOURS_IN_A_DAY = (0..23).to_a

@data = Array.new(DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.size).map!{ Array.new(HOURS_IN_A_DAY.size) }

DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.each do |day|
  HOURS_IN_A_DAY.each do |hour|
    @data[day][hour] = 'something'
  end
end
```

**Method 2:**

```
DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = (0..6).to_a
HOURS_IN_A_DAY = (0..23).to_a

@data = {}

DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.each do |day|
  HOURS_IN_A_DAY.each do |hour|
    @data[day] ||= {}
    @data[day][hour] = 'something'
  end
end
```

The difference between the first method and the second method is that the second one does not allocate memory initially. I feel the second one is a bit inferior when it comes to performance due to the numerous amount of Array copies that has to happen.

However, it is not straight forward in Ruby to find what is happening. So, if someone can explain me which is better, it would be really great!

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered doing something like `time ruby myscript.rb` to see which is faster?  Remember the old adage "measure twice, cut once" from carpentry?  In computing it's "measure once, don't waste your time asking".

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION : I am not only concerned about which is faster, I am also concerned on what is happening behind the scenes. See, in C, Java whenever I initialize an array, I am sure that its a contiguous memory location grabbed in memory. And if a dynamic growing version is needed, lots of Array copies happen within. So, I was just curious to see what would be the best practice.

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: You must learn to let slip your inner control freak, grasshopper.  :D  First make sure your code is both correct and maintainable.  Then worry about performance, damaging maintainability (but **never** correctness!) in limited, well-documented areas only if necessary.  In a language like Ruby you can improve the performance algorithmically (best choice), using code tricks (less optimal) or by jumping down into C implementation if absolutely necessary (last, desperate resort).  Do that at the end of implementation, however, not before you've even started.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in the Java Language Specification that says that Arrays must be contiguous in memory. At least not that I have found.

Comment: Can also initialize an array of arrays without `map`: `@data = Array.new(DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.size) {Array.new(HOURS_IN_A_DAY.size)}`

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: That's more likely to be found in the JVM spec, not the language spec.

Comment: Indeed, look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc10.html and scroll down to newarray.  It strongly implies there in referencing "allocated from the heap" that it's going to be contiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I answer the question you asked, I'm going to answer the question you should have asked but didn't:

> **Q:** Should I focus on making my code readable first, or should I focus on performance first?

**A:** Make your code readable *and correct* first, then, and **only** if there is a performance problem, start to worry about performance by **measuring** where the performance problem is **first** and only **then** making changes to your code.

Now to answer the question you asked, but shouldn't have:

method1.rb:

```
DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = (0..6).to_a
HOURS_IN_A_DAY = (0..23).to_a

10000.times do

  @data = Array.new(DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.size).map!{ Array.new(HOURS_IN_A_DAY.size) }

  DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.each do |day|
    HOURS_IN_A_DAY.each do |hour|
      @data[day][hour] = 'something'
    end
  end

end
```

method2.rb:

```
DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = (0..6).to_a
HOURS_IN_A_DAY = (0..23).to_a

10000.times do

  @data = {}

  DAYS_IN_A_WEEK.each do |day|
    HOURS_IN_A_DAY.each do |hour|
      @data[day] ||= {}
      @data[day][hour] = 'something'
    end
  end

end
```

Results of brain-dead benchmark:

```
$ time ruby method1.rb

real    0m1.189s
user    0m1.140s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time ruby method2.rb

real    0m1.879s
user    0m1.780s
sys 0m0.020s
```

Looks to me like user time usage (the important factor) has method1.rb a lot faster.  You, of course, should not trust this benchmark and should make your own reflecting your actual code use.  This, however, is something you should do only **after** you have determined which code is your performance bottleneck in reality.  (Hint: 99.44% of computer programmers are 100% **wrong** when they guess where their bottlenecks are without measuring!)

Comment: Got it what you were trying to imply.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with just

```
@data = Array.new(7) { Array.new(24) { 'something' }}
```

Or, if you are content having the *same* object everywhere:

```
@data = Array.new(7) { Array.new(24, 'something') }
```

It's much faster, not that it would matter. It is also *much more* readable, which is the most important thing. After all, the purpose of code is communicating intent to the other stakeholders, *not* communicating with the computer.

```
             user   system     total       real
method1  8.969000 0.000000  8.969000 ( 9.059570)
method2 16.547000 0.000000 16.547000 (16.799805)
method3  6.468000 0.000000  6.468000 ( 6.616211)
method4  0.969000 0.015000  0.984000 ( 1.021484)
```

That last line also shows another interesting thing: the runtime is dominated by the time needed to create the 7*24*100000 = 16.8 million `'something'` strings.

And of course there is another important obversation: your `method1` and `method2` that you are comparing against each other do two completely different things! It doesn't even make sense to compare them against each other. `method1` creates an `Array`, `method2` creates a `Hash`.

Your `method1` is equivalent to my first example above:

```
@data = Array.new(7) { Array.new(24) { 'something' }}
```

While `method2` is (*very* roughly) equivalent to:

```
@data = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = 'something' }}
```

Well, except that *your* `method2` initializes the entire `Hash` eagerly, while my method only executes the initialization code lazily in case an uninitialized key is read.

In other words, after running the above initialization code, the `Hash` is still empty:

```
@data # => {}
```

But whenever you try to access a key, it will magically appear:

```
@data[5][17] # => 'something'
```

And it will stay there:

```
@data # => {5 => {17 => 'something'}}
```

Since this code doesn't actually initialize the `Hash`, it is obviously way faster:

```
             user   system     total       real
method5  0.266000 0.000000  0.266000 ( 0.296875)
```

Comment: Hi Jörg!! I was waiting for 'your' reply. The reason I put something there is I am doing something there. Lets just say its not a constant value everytime. And thank for throwing light over the Hash vs Array concept in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped both of the code snippets into separate methods and did some benchmarking. Here are the results:

```
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report ("method1") { 100000.times { method1 } }
  x.report ("method2") { 100000.times { method2 } }
end

             user     system      total        real
method1 11.370000   0.010000  11.380000 ( 11.392233)
method2 17.920000   0.010000  17.930000 ( 18.328318)
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much!! I decipher that the first one is almost twice as good as the second one!!